# How to loop through a db table in mysql and show a column once even thogh it appears on different rows

Tags: mysql, sql

database name = db_structure

```
id | param_id | occupation_id | amount | active 
1.     1            1         20000      1
2.     2            1         20000      1 
3.     3            1         20000      1
4.     1            1         20000      1
5.     2            2         20000      1
6.     3            2         20000      1
7.     4            2         20000      1
```

what query will I write to loop through the table to fetch the records on each row but only show occupation_id once on a table even if it appears more than once?

```
SELECT tbl_salarystructure.occupationid, SUM(amount), tbl_occupation.* 
FROM `tbl_salarystructure` 
INNER JOIN tbl_occupation ON 
  tbl_salarystructure.occupationid = tbl_occupation.id  
WHERE tbl_salarystructure.active = 1 ORDER BY occupationid
```

the result of the query is this when I use php  to fetch the rows on the table

Report table

```
Department | Amount
1            20000
1            20000
1            20000
1            20000
2            20000
2            20000
2            20000
```

I want the department to show once with the total sum of the amount column using php where their occupation id is thesame

Thanks guys, I got the solution to my problem... I changed the ORDER BY in my sql to GROUP BY the column I want and it came out perfect

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect.

Comment: It seems to me that this is more like a formatting issue. If that's the case, it probably should be done at the app/report level, not at the SQL level.

Comment: Read up on aggregate functions with group by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT o.*, SUM(amount)
FROM tbl_occupation o JOIN
     tbl_salarystructure ss      
     ON ss.occupationid = o.id  
WHERE ss.active = 1
GROUP BY o.occupationid;
```

In general, you don't want to use `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY`.  The one exception is when the primary key for the table (or any unique key actually) is one of the `GROUP BY` keys.

Comment: Oh thank you so much.... It worked perfectly just how I wanted it... phewww.